# android - MediaCodec video only decoder framerate control

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Refer to [this](https://github.com/cedricfung/MediaCodecDemo/blob/master/src/io/vec/demo/mediacodec/DecodeActivity.java) link, I just add a simple delay when output buffer available:
                    ByteBuffer buffer = outputBuffers[outIndex];
                    Log.v("DecodeActivity", "We can't use this buffer but render it due to the API limit, " + buffer);

```
                // We use a very simple clock to keep the video FPS, or the video
                // playback will be too fast
                while (info.presentationTimeUs / 1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - startMs) {
                    try {
                        sleep(10);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                decoder.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
```

But when I feed a 25fps video only frames, the decoded video looks like only 10fps (many frames looks like dropped).

But if I add a frameconut to check the fps, it's really 25fps, and if add MediaMuxer to mux the frames in input buffer, it playbacks fine, which means frames actually not been dropped.

So it's wired why fames there but not show on screen, but if I remove the delay, the playback will be very quick (almost 50fps).

Answer (score 0):

Just found issue caused by TextureView, after change TextureView to SurfaceView, it works fine now.

But still not clear why TextureView performance is so bad.